# how to avoid user and password authentication while using import?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

im trying to make web crawler on mathematica 8 .

```
  webcrawler[rooturl_, depth_] :=    Flatten[Rest[
     NestList[
      Union[Flatten[
         Thread[# -> 
             Import[#, "Hyperlinks", 
              "ServerAuthentication" -> False ]] & /@ 
          Last /@ #]] &, {"" -> rooturl}, depth]]];
```

its working well , the only problem is that when ever there i a link with user and password authentication , a box is poping up and i need to click cancel , is there any way to do it automatic ?